# Methods shared among structs

Tags: struct, rust, traits

New to Rust here, apologies for my naiveté.

I want to define some probability distributions, which obviously have differing parameters. But the "interface" (as I know it in Java) should be the same. At the most basic level each distribution should have a `sample` and a `sample_many` method. So I implement a trait:

```
pub trait ERP<T> {
    fn sample(&self) -> T;
    fn sample_many(&self, i: isize) -> Vec<T>;
}
```

Then a specific distribution can be created:

```
pub struct Bernoulli {
    pub p: f64
}

impl ERP<bool> for Bernoulli {
    fn sample(&self) -> bool {
        rand::random::<f64>() < self.p
    }

    fn sample_many(&self, i: isize) -> Vec<bool> {
        (0..i).map(|_| self.sample()).collect()
    }
}
```

My issue is with the `sample_many` method, specifically. This method will be the same code regardless of the kind of distribution, e.g.

```
pub struct Gaussian {
    pub mu: f64,
    pub sigma: f64
}

impl ERP<f64> for Gaussian {
    fn sample(&self) -> f64 {
        // Code unique to each distribution
    }

    fn sample_many(&self, i: isize) -> Vec<f64> {
        (0..i).map(|_| self.sample()).collect() // Code reuse??
    }
}
```

So copying the method here is pretty redundant. Is there a way around this?

Comment: @ker My intent was not to create a compilable example, but just an example for a generalizable issue, hence leaving out `sample` in `Gaussian`

Comment: rust has the `unimplemented!()` macro for such situations. Your code will compile, but do nothing useful. you can see this in http://is.gd/WwsBW2

Comment: For code that is very similar, sometimes an implementation macro makes sense. Though, I think that @ker's default implementation is the most appropriate here. (see macro question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31082179/implementing-a-trait-for-a-trait )

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can create a default implementation for any function in the trait definition. It can still be overwritten by an implementor

```
pub trait ERP<T> {
    fn sample(&self) -> T;
    fn sample_many(&self, i: isize) -> Vec<T> {
        (0..i).map(|_| self.sample()).collect()
    }
}
```

Comment: What if `sample_many ` needs to access strut fields?