# Can not implement io::Read for a custom trait

Tags: rust, traits

I want to implement the `std::io::Read` trait for my custom trait. This is my try:-

```rust
use std::io::Read;

trait Bar {
    fn foo(&self);
}

impl<T: Bar> Read for T {
    fn read(&mut self, buf: &mut [u8]) -> std::io::Result<usize> {
        Ok(0)
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e4a47a17022e29f4670f27ecbff5110a)

Error:-

```
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0119]: conflicting implementations of trait `std::io::Read` for type `&mut _`:
 --> src/lib.rs:7:1
  |
7 | impl<T: Bar> Read for T {
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: conflicting implementation in crate `std`:
          - impl<R> std::io::Read for &mut R
            where R: std::io::Read, R: ?Sized;
  = note: downstream crates may implement trait `Bar` for type `&mut _`

error[E0210]: type parameter `T` must be used as the type parameter for some local type (e.g., `MyStruct<T>`)
 --> src/lib.rs:7:6
  |
7 | impl<T: Bar> Read for T {
  |      ^ type parameter `T` must be used as the type parameter for some local type
  |
  = note: implementing a foreign trait is only possible if at least one of the types for which is it implemented is local
  = note: only traits defined in the current crate can be implemented for a type parameter

error: aborting due to 2 previous errors
```

Comment: `impl<T: Bar> Read for T` means "implement `Read` _for all_ types `T` for which `T: Bar` holds". Is this what you meant to write?

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29256519/i-implemented-a-trait-for-another-trait-but-cannot-call-methods-from-both-traits, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31082179/is-there-a-way-to-implement-a-trait-on-top-of-another-trait and https://users.rust-lang.org/t/implementing-trait-for-trait/13810

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is currently not allowed, as explained in the note:

```
= note: downstream crates may implement trait `Bar` for type `&mut _`
```

You are trying to implement `Read` for all types that implement `Bar`, but you can't guarantee that all implementations of `Bar` (present or future) don't - or won't - implement `Read` already. For example, a user of your crate might implement `Bar` for one of their own types.

Another problem is explained in the second error:

```
= note: implementing a foreign trait is only possible if at least one of the types for which is it implemented is local
= note: only traits defined in the current crate can be implemented for a type parameter
```

You are only allowed to implement a trait if *either* the trait is defined in your crate (`Read` is not) *or* if the type that you are implementing it for is defined in your crate. That means you can't implement `Read` for `T`, because `T` is literally *any* type, including arbitrary types from other crates.

A workaround for this would be to add a function that exposes a `Read` implementation from an arbitrary `T: Bar`:

```
use std::io::Read;

trait Bar {
    fn foo(&self);
    fn as_reader(&self) -> BarRead<&Self> {
        BarRead(self)
    }
}

pub struct BarRead<T>(T);

impl<T: Bar> Read for BarRead<T> {
    fn read(&mut self, buf: &mut [u8]) -> std::io::Result<usize> {
        Ok(0)
    }
}
```

Comment: First edition of the answer is not working for test cases. Example:- https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2a1cfac1f30af10ce90019e28dc221ae . I will look at this approach. Thanks.

Comment: I think your comment relates to a different answer that was deleted, not this one?

Comment: @PeterHall Hi Peter, thanks for the answers, may I ask, why we need explict lifetime to implement Read for BarRead?

Comment: @Sean the explicit lifetime isn't needed. That hasn't always been the case though, so I probably included it out of habit.