# `AsArray` cannot be made into an object when implementing a trait for a trait

Tags: rust, rust-polars, rust-ndarray

Basically I'm trying to make a trait that indicates the ability to be converted into a 2D `ndarray` aka [`ndarray::Array2`](https://docs.rs/ndarray/0.15.3/ndarray/type.Array2.html):

```rust
trait Into2DArray{
    fn to_array(&self) -> Array2<f64>;
}
```

I would like to do this by expanding the existing [`AsArray`](https://docs.rs/ndarray/0.15.3/ndarray/trait.AsArray.html) trait, but Rust forbids me from implementing a third party trait for a third party struct ([`polars::DataFrame`](https://docs.rs/polars/0.14.7/polars/prelude/struct.DataFrame.html#)) for some esoteric reason, so instead I have to make my own trait for this.

Anyway, this works well for `polars::DataFrame`:

```rust
impl Into2DArray for DataFrame {
    fn to_array(&self) -> Array2<f64> {
        return self.to_array();
    }
}
```

However, I also want to implement this for anything that is already convertable into a 2D array, so I implement this trait for the `AsArray` trait mentioned above:

```
impl Into2DArray for AsArray<'_, f64, Ix2> {
    fn to_array(&self) -> Array2<f64> {
        return self.into();
    }
}
```

However the compiler gives me grief for this:

```
   |
26 | impl Into2DArray for AsArray<'_, f64, Ix2> {
   |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `AsArray` cannot be made into an object
   |
   = note: the trait cannot be made into an object because it requires `Self: Sized`
   = note: for a trait to be "object safe" it needs to allow building a vtable to allow the call to be resolvable dynamically; for more information visit <https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/traits.html#object-safety>
```

I understand that has something to do with [object safety](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/traits.html#object-safety) but I thought I had fulfilled all the criteria mentioned on that page, namely the trait doesn't return `Self`, and all the generic parameters of `AsArray` are specified.

What is going wrong, and how can I fix it?

Comment: `impl<T: AsArray<'_, f64, Ix2>> Into2DArray for T {…}`

Comment: `AsArray` is not object safe because of the second rule in the link: *"`Sized` must not be a supertrait. In other words, it must not require `Self: Sized`"*. `AsArray` has the supertrait `Into<_>` which has the supertrait `Sized`.

Comment: `impl<'a, T: AsArray<'a, f64, Ix2>> Into2DArray for T` worked, which is a slight adjustment of @Jmb's answer. If anyone can explain how this is different then I'll happily accept it as an answer.

Comment: This question is a duplicate of [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45116984/the-trait-cannot-be-made-into-an-object) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31082179/is-there-a-way-to-implement-a-trait-on-top-of-another-trait). But although they both contain the same answer as my comment above, I'm afraid neither of them really explains _why_ this is the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you were trying to do is implementing the `Into2DArray` trait for the `AsArray` dynamic trait object. There should have been a warning of using `AsArray` without `dyn` anyway.

But this is not what you actually want. You want to implement it for any type that implements `AsArray`. Just like you did in your comment.

It is important to know the difference between these two things:

```rust
trait NeedThis {
    fn can_be_called_by_the_impl(&self) {}
}

trait ToDoThis {
    fn example(&self);
}

impl ToDoThis for dyn NeedThis {
    fn example(&self) {
        self.can_be_called_by_the_impl()
    }
}

impl NeedThis for u8 {}

fn main() {
    let num: u8 = 0;
    // num.example(); // doesn't work because ToDoThis is not implemented for u8

    let num_as_trait_obj: &dyn NeedThis = &0_u8 as &dyn NeedThis;
    num_as_trait_obj.example(); // works because this time it is a trait object
}
```

```rust
trait NeedThis {
    fn can_be_called_by_the_impl(&self) {}
}

trait ToDoThis {
    fn example(&self);
}

// removing ?Sized would make it the same as T: NeedThis + Sized
impl<T: NeedThis + ?Sized> ToDoThis for T {
    fn example(&self) {
        self.can_be_called_by_the_impl()
    }
}

impl NeedThis for u8 {}

fn main() {
    let num: u8 = 0_u8;
    num.example(); // works because we implemented it for all types that implement NeedThis

    let num_as_trait_obj: &dyn NeedThis = &0_u8 as &dyn NeedThis;
    num_as_trait_obj.example(); // works because dyn NeedThis also implements NeedThis.
    // This is only true because we added ?Sized to the bounds of the impl block.
    // Otherwise it doesn't work because dyn NeedThis is not actually Sized.
    // And a Sized bound is implied by default.
}
```

Comment: Loads of code but hopefully it clarifies things instead of making things more convoluted.

Comment: I find it very strange that `impl ToDoThis for NeedThis` and `impl<T: NeedThis> ToDoThis for T` have such different meanings given that they seem to be saying the same thing. Is there a rationale behind this? Does each syntax have a different name?

Comment: @Migwell `impl ToDoThis for NeedThis` is deprecated nowadays, it would be written `impl ToDoThis for dyn NeedThis` for clarity.  `dyn NeedThis` is a [trait object](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch17-02-trait-objects.html)

Comment: @Migwell they're not saying the same thing: `impl<T: NeedThis> ToDoThis` creates a _different_ function for each type that implements `NeedThis`, whereas `impl ToDoThis for dyn NeedThis` creates a _single_ function that can be used with any `&dyn NeedThis`. See this [playground example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=198a87e81bd6788ad0b44c47c1c02031) showing that  the functions have different addresses in the first case and the same address in the second.